# Is there a way to reset steam achievements or farm steam trading cards?

Tags: steam, achievements, terraria, steam-trading-cards

**Is there currently any viable method in which to reset one's steam achievements?** In this case, for a game like Terraria?

**Is there a way to "farm" steam trading cards?** And what are its mechanics?

Comment: There seems to be 2 separate questions here it may be a good idea to split them up.

Comment: Ok but the answer is true here so not this time

Comment: Those two questions are not related at all.  Therefore, they don't belong in the same question.  Chose one you want to keep, and ask the other as a separate question, please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1. Is there any way to reset the Terraria achievements?**

**Yes**, and **no**. While steam currently has implemented no official method i which to reset achievements (and it is unlikely they ever will), it is possible to use external mods to reset your achievements.

One problem that may arise is the likelihood of your account getting VAC Banned by resetting your achievements. I do not believe that this problem is unfounded and I recommend that you just resign to the fact that as of right now, resetting your achievements in steam legitimately is simply not a possibility.

*And alternate method however, is to set up a new steam account and play from there.*

**2. What is a good way to farm steam trading cards in Terraria?**

I would first like you to consult [this website](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq) to get a better understanding of how Steam Trading Cards work.

Simply put, **you are not able to "farm" steam trading cards.** Instead, you are able to get a certain amount of cards by simply playing the game, through the opening of booster packs or by trading with other members of the community.

> Most games will drop a number of cards equal to about half the number of cards in that game's set of cards. For example, Half-Life 2 has 8 cards in its set, you can receive 4 card drops by playing it. You'll need to collect the other half of the set from other community members.

***So how can you get steam trading cards?***

> You can get trading cards simply by playing one of the [participating games](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq#participating_games). As you play, you'll occasionally receive trading card drops which will be placed in your Steam Inventory.

Another viable method is by getting Booster Packs. Essentially, these booster packs contain trading cards.

> Once you have received all of your card drops, you become eligible for a booster pack, which is a set of 3 trading cards that may include both basic and foil cards. Booster packs are granted randomly to eligible users as more badges are crafted by members of the community. Make sure you log in to Steam each week to maintain eligibility.
>
> Once eligible, your Steam Level increases your rate of receiving a booster pack drop:
>
> - **Level 10:** +20% increase in your drop rate
> - **Level 20:** +40% increase in your drop rate
> - **Level 30:** +60% increase in your drop rate
> - **Level 40:** +80% increase in your drop rate
> - **Level 50:** +100% increase in your drop rate *(i.e. the rate has doubled)*
> - **Etc.**

This is only a summary of the link I provided above. Please check out the link for additional information.

Comment: I've gotten most of my trading cards from buying them on the [Community Market](http://steamcommunity.com/market/).  They're usually $0.05 - $0.20 which works out to less than $1 per completed badge.

Comment: You won't be VAC banned, as Terraria doesn't use VAC.

Answer (score 3):

1. There are 3rd-party programs such as the [Steam Achievement Manager](http://gib.me/sam/) (SAM for short) which allows you to manipulate achievements at your whim.  Note that developers who have locked achievements will prevent you from manipulating those.
2. There are 3rd-party programs which can simulate running a game for you in order to get the card drops needed from the game, all without needing to have the game installed. In fact, as stated before, in Steam Achievement Manager you can simply double click on a game to have it "running" even without it being installed, and you will receive card drops dependent on how many drops you have left.